# I'm trying to use a Python web scraper to pull text from a page that has that text update periodically

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I'll start off by saying that I am a complete and total novice who has almost no idea what he is doing.

I'm attempting to use a web scraper to pull 4 pairs of numbers from a page, the numbers change when modified on a separate page (I cannot use that page to pull the data from) and send it to a text document on my pc. When I pull the html source the text isn't represented there at all (none of the elements that can update or change are).

It looks like this when viewing it with inspect elements
`<div id="openpages"> ==$0 <span class="thisnotes"> ***example text***</span> <div/>`

and this when viewing the page source, or when it pulls the info into pycharm
`<div id='openpages'></div>`

Again I have literally no idea what I'm doing, but I think it's because the page uses javascript to know when it needs to update `<span class="thisnotes">`
I apologise if this is a mind numbingly stupid question question, or stackoverflow is not the right place for it. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, [here are some tips:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it seems page uses JavaScript to add elements and you can't find it in source HTML (and you can't use `requests` with `Beautifulsoup` because they don't run JavaScript). You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run JavaScript. Eventuallu you can use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` to find url used by JavaScript to get data from server - and then you can use `requests` to get it. Usually it sends data as JSON which can be easily converted to Python list or dict and you don't need `Beautifulsoup` to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the DOM usually turns up something. Could you not use "find_element_by_class_name" ?

Can you link to the website?

EDIT: I was able to get the text by using this code:
EDIT: Full code for clarity:

```
#! python3

# These two lines import Selenium webdriver and Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# These lines tell browser open links in new tabs (personal preference)
opts = Options()
opts.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0)
opts.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)

# This line defines the browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

# This line loads the website
browser.get('https://app.roll20.net/campaigns/journal/6581887/handout/-MAhsToCYmASlnZzZJST')

# These lines are explained below
digits = browser.find_element_by_class_name('thisnotes')
output = digits.get_attribute('innerText')
print(output)
```

This code finds the element by class name and assigns this to a variable that I named "digits". Then we use the "get_attribute" to take whatever is in the 'innerText' attribute and assign this to a variable I named "output".

This will make a lot more sense if you look at the DOM properties. To do that, you right-click (or control-click for OSX) on the element (those numbers on the site) and choose "Inspect Element". It will show you the HTML with the span class highlighted. You then right-click or control-click on that and choose "Show DOM properties." Once I am in there it shows me that class name = "thisnotes"

I don't typically use class_name though, more often xpath or css_selector.

Comment: [This is the url of the page](https://app.roll20.net/campaigns/journal/6581887/handout/-MAhsToCYmASlnZzZJST), the text I'm trying to get is the numbers **1 , 1 | 2 , 2 | 3 , 3 | 4 , 4**. Again I apologise, but I'm not versed at all with any of this, would `"find_element_by_class_name"` be a string of code I input into PyCharm, or is that something in the html? I'm also not quire sure what DOM refers to sorry!

Comment: No problem. I edited my answer, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I again apolgise for not fully understanding, and thank you very much for your help so far! I understand the DOM properties now, but the code I'm having trouble with. When I copied yours browser wasn't defined, so I installed slenium but that didn't change anything, and now I'm not exactly sure what to do. Again I'm very sorry for being a pain!

Comment: No problem, I included the full code with comments to explain. The selenium docs are really helpful: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/